# gain plot margins in R

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to fit a second ylab on the right of my plot but I'm not able to gain the extra space needed. Drawing the scale values inside the graph could be a solution if this was not possible.
My code (simulated data but the problem with the right margin is there):

```
dev.new( width= 16, height= 7 )
par( cex= 0.9 )
plot( 1:100, type="n", xlab = "", ylab = "", axes = F, las = 2, cex = 0.7 )
axis( 4, at = c ( 0, 30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180 ), labels = c( "0", "30", "60", "90", "120", "150", "180" ), las = 0, cex.axis = .8,col.lab = "gray80",
tck = 0.01 )
rect( 153, -5.5, 169, 185, col = "gray80", border = NA)
rect( 246, -5.5, 272, 185, col = "gray80", border = NA)
lines( 1:200, col = "gray20" )
#text("Moon phase (º)", 330, 90, cex = .9 )
mtext(side = 4, text = "Moon phase (º)", line = 2, cex = .9 )
mtext(side = 1, text = "Dates", line = 4, cex = .9 )

par( new = T )
plot( 1:220, type = "n", lwd= 1.2, xlab= "", ylab= "Photoperiod (h)", axes = F, cex = .8, col.lab = "red" )
axis( side= 1, at = c ( 1, 20, 51, 82, 112, 143, 173, 204, 235, 264, 295, 324 ), labels = c ( "12 Jun'07", "1 Jul'07", "1 Aug'07", "1 Sep'07", "1 Oct'07", "1 Nov'07", "1 Dec'07", "1 Jan'08", "1 Feb'08", "1 Mar'08", "1 Apr'08", "30 Apr'08" ), las = 2, cex.axis = .75 )
axis ( side = 2, at = c( 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 ), labels = c( "12", "13", "14", "15", "16" ), cex.axis = .8, las = 2)
box()
```

Thank you for your help,

Santi

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of your plot? -- I tested your code and I saw the second axis on the right site (nevertheless the one on the left site was badly adjusted...).

Comment: I had the same difficulty with this question. What was missing was a statement that the error was that the "Moon phase" was outside the margin area. The obvious problem was with clumped up positioning of the y-axis on the left.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See argument *mar* of `par`. This set the margins of your plot area (bottom, left, top, right; see `?par` for details).

```
dev.new( width= 16, height= 7 )
## set outer margins
par( mar=c(5, 4, 4, 4), cex= 0.9 )
plot( 1:100, type="n", xlab = "", ylab = "", axes = F, las = 2, cex = 0.7 )
axis( 4, at = c ( 0, 30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180 ), labels = c( "0", "30", "60", "90", "120", "150", "180" ), las = 0, cex.axis = .8,col.lab = "gray80",
tck = 0.01 )
rect( 153, -5.5, 169, 185, col = "gray80", border = NA)
rect( 246, -5.5, 272, 185, col = "gray80", border = NA)
lines( 1:200, col = "gray20" )
#text("Moon phase (º)", 330, 90, cex = .9 )
mtext(side = 4, text = "Moon phase (º)", line = 2, cex = .9 )
mtext(side = 1, text = "Dates", line = 4, cex = .9 )

par( new = T )
plot( 1:220, type = "n", lwd= 1.2, xlab= "", ylab= "Photoperiod (h)", axes = F, cex = .8, col.lab = "red" )
axis( side= 1, at = c ( 1, 20, 51, 82, 112, 143, 173, 204, 235, 264, 295, 324 ), labels = c ( "12 Jun'07", "1 Jul'07", "1 Aug'07", "1 Sep'07", "1 Oct'07", "1 Nov'07", "1 Dec'07", "1 Jan'08", "1 Feb'08", "1 Mar'08", "1 Apr'08", "30 Apr'08" ), las = 2, cex.axis = .75 )
axis ( side = 2, at = c( 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 ), labels = c( "12", "13", "14", "15", "16" ), cex.axis = .8, las = 2)
box()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, mar() solves the problem. I tried to put it inside dev.new() and obviously didn't work

Answer (score 4):

In your code use on line #2:

```
par( cex= 0.9,mar=c(6,4,6,4) )
```